# Selection Indicator of tab bar not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I am newbie to iOS.

I have implemented a tabBarController along with the 4 tabBar items through Storyboard.  Now, I need to customise my tab bar as shown in the image below. I have set the background for the tab bar.

```
 + (UIImage *)imageFromColor:(UIColor *)color {
     CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
     CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
     UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     return image;
 }


 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

      [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

      [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[AppDelegate imageFromColor:[UIColor blackColor]]];

      return YES;
   }
```

The background for the tab bar is set without any problems.

When I try to set the colour for the selected tab bar item, it does not work. I don't know why?

```
[[UITabBar appearance]setSelectionIndicatorImage:[AppDelegate imageFromColor:[UIColor orangeColor]]];
```

I need to customise my tab bar like this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should remember that configuration of the UITabBar should be done in `AppDelegate.m`:

You should add `[[UITabBar appearance]setSelectionIndicatorImage:[AppDelegate imageFromColor:[UIColor orangeColor]]];` in the 
 `AppDelegate.m` in `applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Secondly in you're case you should provide tab bar item selected state example:

```
   UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController   *)self.window.rootViewController;
   UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
   UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

   //We set title
   tabBarItem1.title = @"Home";

   //We set highlighted state
   [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"]];

   // Change the tab bar background
   UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
   [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
   // Tab bar active background
   [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_selected.png"]];
```

Comment: i have added it in AppDelegate.m Itself

Comment: even this is setting only background

Answer (score 0):

Setting selection indicator image directly to tabbar along with appearance worked for me.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

     UITabBarController *tabBarContr = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_selection_indicator.png"]];

    // iOS7 hack: to make selectionIndicatorImage appear on the selected tab on the first app run
    [[tabBarContr tabBar] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bar_selection_indicator.png"]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: even this i am getting same result

Comment: just try to attach screenshots question what you are getting that may help get the problem more clearly